# How best to connect two optical limit switches to share one I/O pin

Tags: cnc, optical

I'm trying to build a CNC laser engraver using a scrap industrial CNC gantry as a donor. The system already has optical limit switches for the max & min on each axis. I can't use the current controller because it is propitiatory and doesn't accept g-code. Also the wires are already cut!

I would like to use GRBL and the Arduino Uno as the controller for this system but this means only 1 I/O pin for combined max/min limit control per axis.

The limit switches are this type: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/110958.pdf

They are LOW when the limit flag enters the switch.

How can I connect them so that they will be compatible with GRBL? https://github.com/gnea/grbl/wiki/Wiring-Limit-Switches

Would the attached image work as a circuit by having both limit switches share the same I/O line in parallel? Will the transistor in the limit switch be able to sink the other to ground?

[image: Suggestion for connection without noise filtering]

[image: Suggestion to connect with noise filtering]

Comment: Often the home switch is adequate if the travel limits can be set in software. My GRBL-controlled laser is set up this way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work.

You need to add a pull-up resistor (from the OUT node to VCC) to be sure the output goes high when none of the limits have been hit. This can be anything from maybe 500 ohms to 10 kohms, with lower values giving faster response when exiting the limit condition and higher values giving lower power consumption when in the limit condition. If you have no other reason to choose, 4.7 kohm is a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1):

tl; dr: yes, it can work. Add a pull-up resistor to the collectors and you’re good to go.

With the switches wired together with a pull-up to VCC, either end-of-travel switch can activate and pull the OUT line low. The switches are 'open collector', which means they can only sink current to ground and thus be safely wired together as a 'wire-or'. There is no harm in both sensors pulling the line low at the same time, even though that's a physical impossibility.

Because the open collectors can only sink current, they must be tied with a pull-up resistor to VCC. A value of 1K-5K is is a good choice for a high-noise environment like this. A small capacitance to ground (100pF, say) can help too.

The limitation of this setup is you can't tell one limit from the other. With known-good wiring this shouldn't pose a problem as the servo index process will know which direction the actuator is running as it discovers each limit switch. If there is a possibility of a motor miswire, you will need to rethink this.